# ML model to transform words

Tags: neural-network, nlp, convolutional-neural-network

I build model that on input have correct word. On output there is possible word written by human (it contain some errors). My training dataset looks that:

```
input - output  
hello - helo  
hello - heelo  
hello - hellou  
between - betwen  
between - beetween  
between - beetwen  
between - bettwen  
between - bitween
```

etc.
During preprocessing I add a measure of the distortion of a word. Then I hardcoding letters for numbers.
My current model's using CNN. The number of neurons of input is the same as the longest word in training dataset and the number of neurons of output is the same as the longest word in traning dataset. 
This model doesn't work as I excepted. Word on the output is not look as I except.
eg.

```
input - output
house - gjrtdd
```

Question:

How can I build/improve model for this task? Is CNN a good idea? What other methods can I use for this task?

Comment: This task is called _spelling correction_ or _spell checking_. There is a large body of work on it.

Comment: Rather I say reverse spelling correction. My input is correct word, as an output I want not correct word.

Comment: Have you checked my answer? You can train a Generator (in the GAN concept) to do exactly that.

Comment: Oh sorry. Once you have a spell corrected corpus, it is almost trivial to find the reverse map. If you collect statistics, you could also obtain a distribution over the candidates, since each input will correspond to multiple outputs.

Comment: @Emre It's not so trivial. One letter can be changed in dependence of their neighborhood. So it is not one to one change.

Comment: Of course, that's why you would keep track of the context; the past word or two should be plenty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a totally different approach, using [Generative Adversarial Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_adversarial_network).

For this purpose you need:

1. A Generator
2. A Discriminator

See the scheme (credit O'Reilly):

[image]

The *"Real Images"* block in the scheme should be your *training dataset* (or ground truth). The Generator should generate the distorted words and the Discriminator should verify if the word is "adequately" distorted, based on a criterion of your choice, which can be any similarity measure between known words (database) and the generated one. Both the Generator and the Discriminator get trained **on-the-go** while in the training phase and in the end you will have two trained networks, of which the Generator would be very useful for your purpose.

Helpful source: https://deeplearning4j.org/generative-adversarial-network

Comment: Is GAN working with 1D?

Comment: Yes, GAN is a concept.

Comment: GAN is unsupervised learning algorithm, so real images will be 'correct words'? Do I need my output (NOT correct words)?

Comment: Exactly, I would use the real words as "real images" in the figure. The purpose of the Generator should be to produce imaginary words that comply with the characteristics that you want (similar up to a certain degree to real words). These characteristics (measure of similarity) will be learned by the Discriminator, which will help the Generator to improve itself.

Comment: GAN is semi-supervised, i.e. it needs samples of the "real" class and it will generate the "fake" class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sequence-to-sequence model based on different RNN (LSTM for example) types. As far as I know, seq2seq models has been applied to spell checking. You should take a look to the existing work on spell checking and figure out how to use them in your problem.

Maybe you can treat correct word - misspelled word pairs as paraphrases and solve the problem as a paraphrase generation task.